# Delete List row when Timer is completed with some animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, countdowntimer

how to delete list row when the timer is completed with some sort of animation.i have tried the below code but it wont works properly please check this and please let me know where i am doing wrong.

this is my code inside adapter getview() method

```
final TextView tv = holder.timer;

                CountDownTimer cdt = counters.get(tv);
                if(cdt!=null)
                {
                    cdt.cancel();
                    cdt=null;
                }

                cdt = new CountDownTimer(Long.parseLong(product.getOfferEndTime()), 1000)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                    {

                        int minutes = 0;
                        int seconds = 0;
                        String sDate = "";

                        if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                        {
                            minutes = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
                        }

                        millisUntilFinished -= (minutes*DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

                        if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
                        {
                            seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                        }

                        sDate += " "+"00"+":"+String.format("%02d",minutes)+":"+String.format("%02d",seconds);
                        tv.setText(sDate.trim());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {


                        tv.setText("Finished");

                        removeListItem(v,position) ;    

                    }
                };
```

this is my removeListItem method inside adapter class

```
protected void removeListItem(View rowView, final int positon) {
        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        rowView.startAnimation(animation);
        Handler handle = new Handler();
        handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ListOnGoing.productListAdapter.remove(getItem(positon));
                ListOnGoing.productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 1000);
}
```

please help me out of this problem.thanks

Comment: Please elaborate what doesn't work properly exactly. Is the removeListItem method even get called? Does the animation look poor?

Comment: Actually positions are wrongly get deleted not the required item is deleting
@Zsolt